# VHDL core synthesis and implementation in Vivado

Tags: aes, vhdl, fpga

I am currently developing an AES encryption core for a Pynq-Z1 FPGA board. I would like to see the routing of the logic in FPGA logic and timing summary of the design.

The project synthesises, but it results in a warning saying that I am using exceeding the number of IOB blocks on the package. This is understandable because the core takes in and outputs a 4 x 4 matrix.

Instead, I would like to have "internal I/O" in order to see the routing on FPGA fabric. How would I go about doing this? Currently, the device view shows an empty topology (shown below) but my synthesised design utilises 4148 LUT and 389 FF. I expect to see some CLBs highlighted.

[design device view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZJsX.png)

I appreciate any feedback and reference to any application notes which might further progress my FPGA understanding.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple wrapper around your core with a serial interface. Something like:

```
entity wrapper is
  port(clk, rst, dsi, dsi_core, shift_out: in std_ulogic;
       di: in std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
       dso_core: out std_ulogic;
       do: out std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0)
     );
end entity wrapper;

architecture rtl of wrapper is

  signal di_core, do_core, do_buffer: std_ulogic_vector(127 downto 0);

begin

  u0: entity work.core(rtl)
    port map(clk, rst, dsi_core, di_core, dso_core, do_core);

  input_process: process(clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      if rst = '1' then
        di_core <= (others => '0');
      elsif dsi = '1' then
        di_core <= di & di_core(127 downto 8);
      end if;
    end if;
  end process input_process;

  output_process: process(clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      if rst = '1' then
        do_buffer <= (others => '0');
      elsif dso_core = '1' then
        do_buffer <= do_core;
      elsif shift_out = '1' then
        do_buffer <= do_buffer(119 downto 0) & X"00";
      end if;
    end if;
  end process output_process;

  do <= do_buffer(127 downto 120);

end architecture rtl;
```

The wrapper just receives inputs, one byte at a time (when `dsi = '1'`) and shifts them in a 128-bits register that is connected to the 128-bits input of your core. When 16 bytes have been entered the environment asserts `dsi_core` to instruct the core that the 128-bits input can be sampled and processed. The environment waits until the core asserts `dso_core`, signalling that the processing is over and the 128-bits output is available on the `do_core` output port of core. When `dso_core` is asserted the wrapper samples `do_core` in a 128-bits register (`do_buffer`). The environment can now read the leftmost byte of `do_buffer` which drives the `do` output port of the wrapper. The environment asserts `shift_out` to shift `do_buffer` one byte to the left and read the next byte...

This kind of wrapper is a very common practice when you want to test in the real hardware a sub-component of a larger system. As it frequently happens that the number of IOs of sub-components exceeds the number of available IOs, serial input-output solves this. Of course there is a significant latency overhead due to the IO operations but it is just for testing, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Your demands are contradictory.
If the design can not place all the I/Os it can not show all the routing as it has not all the begin and/or endpoints. You should reduce your I/O.

The simplest way is to have a real or imaginary interface which much less pins.

An imaginary interface is one which is syntactically correct, reduces your I/Os but will never be used in real life so does not have to be functionally correct.

As it happens you are the third person to ask about reducing I/O in the last weeks and I posted an (untested) SPI interface which has a parameter to generate an arbitrary number of internal inputs and outputs. You can find it here: [How can I assign a 256-bit std_logic_vector input](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/380716/how-can-i-assign-a-256-bit-std-logic-vector-input/380735#380735)